# Solve $Ux=y$ for $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm a so confused.... So the question wants to call $A=LU$ where L is the lower triangular matrix and U is the upper one. Think of $Ax=b$ as $LUx=b$ (duhr).

I was just going to multiple the two matrix together and then solve for the unknown but  it want us to these two steps....

1) let $Ux=y$ so $LUx=b$ is $Ly=b$. Solve this system. (does this mean find the inverse or turn it to an identity)?

2) Solve the system for U(x) = y for x.

a)

$$\begin{bmatrix}  
1&0&0\\ -2&3&0\\  2&4&1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}  2&-1&3\\ 0&1&2\\  0&0&4\\ \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2}\\x_{3} \end{bmatrix} =  
\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2 \\3 \end{bmatrix}$$

1)
I was thinking just do a matrix multiplication. For the two matrix but realised that's the wrong way to go and now i'm sure determinants is not the way to go. First question: what is the significance of the matrix being and upper and lower triangles namely for this scenario?

so we have to let y equals..

$$\begin{bmatrix}  2&-1&3\\ 0&1&2\\  0&0&4\\ \end{bmatrix} 
x = y$$

Then solve 
$$\begin{bmatrix}  
1&0&0\\ -2&3&0\\  2&4&1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}y=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2 \\3 \end{bmatrix}$$

What do they mean by solve? Just row reduce until i get to an identity matrix? Is RHS affected?

Comment: the main idea here is that it is easier to solve a triangular system ($Ux = y$ or $Ly = b$) than solving the full system $Ax = b.$

Answer (score 1):

So i'm thinking like for part 1 a

$$\begin{bmatrix}  
1&0&0\\ -2&3&0\\  2&4&1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}y=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2 \\3 \end{bmatrix}$$

x=1

-2(1) + 3y = 2 --> y=4/3

hence
2 + 4*(4/3) + z = 3 --> z = -13/3

$$y=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\\frac{4}{3} \\ \frac{-13}{3} \end{bmatrix}$$

Then part 2 is... 
$$\begin{bmatrix}  
2&-1&3\\ 0&1&2\\  0&0&4\\ 
\end{bmatrix}x=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\\frac{4}{3} \\ \frac{-13}{3} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$x=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{28}{3}\\\frac{7}{2} \\ \frac{-13}{12} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: What do you guys think?

Comment: That's the right method, and the algebra and arithmetic look right. However, if you call a vector $y$, call its entries $y_1, y_2$ and $y_3$, or at least something different from $x, y$ and $z$.

Comment: The values of $x$ are incorrect. Check your work because your method is correct, overall. Specifically $x_1$ is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah i realize i made an input error i just wanted to illustrate my idea and it seems alright.